# Is there a way to identify the font used in an image?

Tags: image, fonts

I want to identify the font of text shown in an image.  Please refer to the below image. I want to find the font family and font size which generate the perfect match text( perfect I mean each pixel). e.g. the following 7x20 figure shows a simple image with digit 1, I need to identify the font and size used to generate the text and then converted to image.

[image]

Please help!